# Django mptt database migration error

Tags: python, django, django-mptt, mptt

im trying to get mptt working with my current project, but having issues with the database migration.

here is my model

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Section(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

and im running this in the command line:

```
sudo python manage.py makemigrations core
```

but seem to be getting and error related to the level field

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'level' to section without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Level' is automatically added by MPTTModel to denote the 'depth' of a particular node in the tree. If you haven't created the tree structure yet, it should be safe to choose option 1 and default everything to level 0 (root). If you do not have the tree structure set up yet, this should be fine and should get adjusted as you work with the tree later.

If you already have a tree structure in mind and you need to reflect that in your data, you will still need to do this, but you will need to follow it with a (probably handwritten) [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to set the right values.

Comment: Just to remember that the level 1 is a child of the default mptt model that is set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

--- Update 2022 ---

As far as I see you can set everything to 0 for `level`, `lft`, `rght` and `tree_id`:

ex:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'level' to section without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

After you set all your values to zero and migrate, you tree will look like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name":"first test tree",
  "lft": 0,
  "rght": 0,
  "tree_id": 0,
  "level": 0,
  "parent": null
}
```

Then you need to go inside the shell and rebuild all trees:

```py
Section.objects.rebuild()
```

After your rebuild command is done your trees will be set as normal, able to create new children:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "first test tree",
   "lft": 1,
   "rght": 2,
   "tree_id": 1,
   "level": 0,
   "parent": null
}
```

**Other approach**:

You can also add the `rebuild()`command within your model after save; Great for those who don't have access to the database or production termial:

```py
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Section(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # before save
        super(Section, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # after save...
        try:
            # get all objects from the Section table.
            trees = Section.objects.all()
            # loops through all values.
            for tree in trees:
                # checks if there is default=0 and if yes rebuild the trees.
                if tree.lft or tree.rght or tree.tree_id == 0:
                    Section.objects.rebuild() 
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
```